# How export big data (>1mln) to excel file use only interop.excel

Tags: c#, database, office-interop

I need to export large amounts of data> 1 million.
Here is the finished function, but it works very slowly.

```
 public void ExportToExcel(string path)
        {
            var doc = new Excel.Application();
            var wb = doc.Workbooks.Add();
            Excel._Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)doc.ActiveSheet;
            ws.Cells[1, "A"] = "Дата";
            ws.Cells[2, "B"] = "Имя";
            ws.Cells[3, "C"] = "Фамилия";
            ws.Cells[4, "D"] = "Отчество";
            ws.Cells[5, "E"] = "Город";
            ws.Cells[6, "F"] = "Страна";
            var check = pers.AsNoTracking().ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < check.Count(); i++)
            {
                ws.Cells[i + 2, "A"] = check.ElementAt(i).Date;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, "B"] = check.ElementAt(i).FirstName;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, "C"] = check.ElementAt(i).LastName;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, "D"] = check.ElementAt(i).SurName;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, "E"] = check.ElementAt(i).City;
                ws.Cells[i + 2, "F"] = check.ElementAt(i).Country;
            }

            wb.SaveAs(path);
        }
```

As I understand it, List goes over this way for a very long time, I made breakpoints and in 10 seconds there were only 1000 records. This is very bad.

Are there any ways to quickly write to Excel. May I use a different collection? I need to achieve a speed of at least 10-20 seconds to insert 1 million data.

Comment: Have you tried using ForEach, or perhaps a Parallel foreach loop instead. Another thing you may want to try is instead of using a List, try using an Array. I am not quite sure how C# handels lists internally, but since you are indexing the check list for data each time, it has to iterate over all of its values (assuming regular list implementation) in order to get to it. An array would have a look up time of O(1), whilst a List is O(n)

Comment: Also, if pers is a database table, and assuming this is the desired behavior, you are getting every single person from the database. This can cause a tremendous amount of overhead, if possible it would be better to pass some filters (Like an orgId for example) before we call .ToList() in order to reduce overhead and the number of data we need to work with

Comment: an array idea is unlikely to work ...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can speed this up:

- Use OLEDB connection to Excel and SQL queries (this requires the connector to be installed). This is the quickest way.
- Write large arrays in one go, instead of line by line. This will still take a while but it will be far quicker than the way you're currently doing it.

Using OLEDB:

```cs
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn ;
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmd = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
String sql = null;
MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='c:\\path\\to\\excelfile.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
conn.Open();
cmd.Connection = conn;
sql = "Insert into [Sheet1$] (id,name) values('5','e')";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

To use arrays you have to first build up your array:

```cs
//10 rows, 5cols
string[,] array = new string[10, 5];
...assign array
Range("A1:E10").value=array;
```

Writing a large array in one go as above is much quicker than going line by line which is painstakingly slow with excel interop.